# Best way to clear a group's cache in Joomla via php, from an administrator plugin?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, plugin, cache

So background: I'm making a caching plugin that clears our site and CDN caches when content is saved in the administrator backend. In this instance, I want to clear the site cache for one group.

My original attempt looked something like this:

```
$cache = JFactory::getCache('cachegroup');
$cache->clean();
```

That didn't work. I did some research and saw [SharkyKZ in the Joomla forums recommend this structure](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=963903):

```
$cache = JCache::getInstance('callback');
$cache->clean('cachegroup');
```

That also didn't work for me. I suspected it had something to do with the fact that caching is disabled on our site, so I tried adding `$cache->setCaching(1);` to both sets of code and that didn't work either.

Finally I dug into the Joomla code and looked at how their cache component handles it; and ended up with this working code:

```
$conf = JFactory::getConfig();

$options = array(
    'defaultgroup' => '',
    'storage'      => $conf->get('cache_handler', ''),
    'caching'      => true,
    'cachebase'    => $conf->get('cache_path', JPATH_SITE . '/cache')
);

$cache = JCache::getInstance('', $options);
$cache->clean('cachegroup');
```

So I have working code, but I would...

1. Like to understand why it works, and
2. Like to know if there is a simpler or superior way to accomplish this.

### Update

This problem doesn't seem to be reproducible within a site template, but I still have the problem within a plugin. So I'm going to give an expanded example of the code structure to help spot problems.

```
<?php

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class plgContentFncaching extends JPlugin
{
    function onContentAfterSave($context, $article, $isNew) {
        // Banner items
        if($context == "com_banners.banner") {
            // Does not work
            plgContentFNCaching::problemClearBannerCache();

            // Works
            plgContentFNCaching::workingClearBannerCache();
        }
    }

    function problemClearBannerCache() {
        $cache = JFactory::getCache('pinnedbanners');
        $cache->setCaching(1);
        $cache->clean();
    }

    function workingClearBannerCache() {
        $conf = JFactory::getConfig();
        
        $options = array(
            'defaultgroup' => '',
            'storage'      => $conf->get('cache_handler', ''),
            'caching'      => true,
            'cachebase'    => $conf->get('cache_path', JPATH_SITE . '/cache')
        );

        $cache = JCache::getInstance('', $options);
        $cache->clean('pinnedbanners');
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not really understand what you would like to clean from the cache when the caching is disabled basically? Your last code sample In your question however shows that the caching is set to `true`. Your question is ambiguous this way.

Comment: So it looks like that your last code sample works because in the options caching gets enabled. Thus `clean()` method returns `true`.

Comment: I also do not see however why the other codes do not work at `setCaching(1)`.

Comment: The reason is that I want to prevent Joomla and third party apps from caching. Then when I want to cache something, I just set caching to 1 for the group. This has worked pretty well until I wanted to clear the cache!

Comment: In the last code sample, I was copying code right out of Joomla's caching component so that's where I got the `true`. But yeah if that is what's making it work I'd like to understand why setting `setCaching(1)` doesn't work.

Comment: I see your points.

Comment: In this function: `problemClearBannerCache()`, `clean()` method is misspelled as `clear()` at BannerCache. Tomorrow I can check your code more... if needed of course.

Comment: @Zollie OOPS, corrected. Still having the issue with the `clean()` (just ran again) but definitely good to have the correct code in the example, thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer with what I see in your plugin code as the problem. I hope that is it.

Comment: @Zollie saw your update and gave it a try but it still didn't work. It's bugged me that the caching code works in the template but not in the plugin so I did a var_dump of the cache object in both contexts and found the cause of the problem. Details are in my answer. Thanks; hopefully this helps the next person who has this problem!

Comment: Well, it’s good that you’ve finally found it and solved it. However, I put my sample code in a content plugIn at `onContentAfterDisplay` event as a test just for checking the code within a content plugin and it worked for me without a problem. Even the `cachebase` is correctly set in the cache object. So, I still cannot duplicate what you got in your plugin.

Comment: I’ll check it with other Plugin events to see if it is relevant In the question.

Comment: I just checked this on `onContentAfterSave` event too and yes, I can say that Base cache folder path depends on the plugin event, not on the plugin itself. So, if the plugin event is triggered from admin area then the `cachebase` is going to be in `administrator/cache` folder, but if the Plugin event is triggered from frontend, then the code in the plugin works in the default cache folder.

Comment: I also edited my answer just to clear this subject more for later researchers/developers.

Comment: @Zollie ooh so it's the context that the plugin is used from, that makes sense. I've made yours the accepted answer for filling in the last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: :) we cleared that from every angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing - and as **@Obscerno** stated - in some plugins the default cache directory is going to be on administrator path. It became obvious that depending on the triggered plugin events, the cache object is using different `cachebase` directory. If the plugin event is triggered from the back-end then the default cache directory is going to be on `.../administrator/cache` path on default administrator root, and if the plugin event is triggered from front-end then the normal default cache directory will be used. **So,** **it depends on** which plugin event you are running your cache handling methods.

Thus you can and you should define **'cachebase'** after you called the **Cache** object:

```
    $myCache = JFactory::getCache('my_cache_plugin');
    $myCache->options['cachebase'] = JPATH_SITE . '/cache';
    $myCache->setCaching(1);

    // var_dump($myCache); die; // debug/check

    $dataToCache = "<h2>From the content plugin on aftersave event this works now</h2>";

    $myCache->store($data = $dataToCache, $id = 'yep1', $group = 'my_cache_plugin'); // you will find the cached data in the 'cache/my_cache_plugin' subfolder

    $myCache->clean('my_cache_plugin', 'group'); // $myCache->clean(); also deletes this cache folder.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with the cache being disabled. It is that the plugin is using a different `cachebase` setting than the cache that saved the data.

The cache that saved the data used the site cache folder located at `/cache`, while the plugin is using the cache folder located at `/administrator/cache`. It doesn't see the data because it's looking in the wrong place.

The reason the working code given in the question works is because it explicitly sets the cachebase to the site cache:

```
$options = array(
    'defaultgroup' => '',
    'storage'      => $conf->get('cache_handler', ''),
    'caching'      => true,
    'cachebase'    => $conf->get('cache_path', JPATH_SITE . '/cache') // <- Here.
);
```

As far as compacting the code goes, you can get away with this:

```
$options = array('caching' => true, 'cachebase' => JPATH_SITE . '/cache');
$cache = JCache::getInstance('',$options);
$cache->clean('cachegroup');
```

Comment: Regarding your suggested edit, please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/4790020/2943403 and https://decisions.typo3.org/t/should-we-use-fully-qualified-function-fqn-calls-like-is-array-in-the-core/392

Comment: Thank you @mickmackusa, I learned something new today! In future edits I'll be sure to leave those be.